# Difference between `devtools::install` and build manually considering `system.file`

Tags: r, devtools

I'm quite a newbie in R, however, I thought that `devtools::install` and building a package manually in RStudio do the same thing. I've never noticed any differences.

However, today I wanted to access some files in my package via `system.file("extdata", package="MyPackage")` and always got `""` as return value. I double checked it that the folder `MyPackage` exist in `~\R\R-4.1.3\library\`.

Only after running `devtools::install()` inside my project, `system.file("extdata", package="MyPackage")` gave me the absolute path to the folder as intended.

Can you explain this?

Comment: You need to give more information about the package.  We need to know the file structure, and what exactly you mean by "building a package manually".

Comment: the example refers to package that I've build my own - nothing official. `extdata` is located in the project root under `inst/`. With building a package manually I meaning using `CTRL+SHIFT+B` in RStudio

Comment: The behavior of `CTRL-SHIFT-B` depends on your config, specifically in the `Tools | Project Options | Build Tools` dialog, there's the "use devtools package" checkbox, and "Install and restart additional options".  But I can't think of any options that would leave out `inst/extdata`. It might be mentioned in `.RBuildIgnore`, but then I'd expect it not to show up whichever way you installed it.

Comment: Some possible explanations:   you're using different `lib.loc` options in the install and in `system.file`, so it's searching in the wrong place.  Does `.libPaths()` list other libraries?  Is something equivalent to `~\R\R-4.1.3\library\.` listed first? Does `system.file()` find other files, e.g. `DESCRIPTION`? Does `extdata` exist as a subdir when you look at the folder?

Comment: Are you using renv to manage your package project?
I just discovered the same weird behavior when using a renv managed R package project. When running `devtools::install()` it will install the package into the renv cache library. When running `R CMD INSTALL` via the Install&Restart Button, the package will be installed into the R local system library.